# How do I complete the Crispy Critters achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The *Crispy Critters* Act III challenge achievement says to "Use a Demon Forge to kill 3 Tormented Stingers at once".

I am assuming that the fire-breathing heads on the sides of the path in the last parts of Act III are Demon Forges.

Tormented Stingers are hard to come by in the last sections of Act III. Their non-achievement worthy cousins, the Stygian crawlers are quite prevalent. I only seem to spot Tormented stingers when they spawn surrounding a Hell Bringer Trap in groups of 6 or rarely from cocoons, 1 at a time.

Kiting these hard-to-find little pests is quite the pain as they pretty much die in one hit and often get too close when I'm stuck in the middle of a swarm of other mobs as I try to get them to what I assume are Demon Forges or get taken out by my follower before I can dismiss. Even when I get them there, they tend to circle around me which is no good as the assumed Demon Forges fire in a straight line with rather narrow spread, meaning that either some of them won't get hit or they won't all die at once.

I've been trying this as a Monk, but I'm considering the Demon Hunter's caltrops, assuming they don't kill the little crawlies. **What is an effective strategy to getting this achievement?** Are the things I assume to be Demon Forges, actually Demon Forges? Is there a more consistent location where I can get Tormented Stingers to spawn for this achievement? Is there a particular class/skill needed to do this successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a video of the process:

> The Stingers can spawn from Infernal Cocoons (for me 1 spawned for every 3 cocoons, roughly).
>
> They also have a chance to spawn when you approach Hell Bringers, and if they do, 5 will spawn in a circle around you.
>
> The best place I found to do this achievement was in the Tower of the Damned level 1.
>
> - Start at the quest Kill Azmodan or The Second Heart and use the waypoint to travel to the Tower of the Damned.
> - Run to the eastern side of the platforms and look for a Hell Bringer. If it's not there you can leave, reset it and go look again.
> - Try to remove your weapon and damage Tormented Stingers to about half hp. If you don't it seems killing them doesn't count for you and you do not get the achievement.

Comment: Finally got this. It took forever. I swear I met the criteria dozens of times and the game would not give it to me. I succeeded on Tower of the Cursed Level 1. At one point during my very many attempts, I ran into a scenario on Arreat Crater Level 1 with two Morlu Incinerators summoning an Oppressor and shortly after killing them, something like 14 Tormented Stingers and a Colossal Golgor spawned - It still didn't give me the achievement toasting at least 10 of them with varying degrees of simultaneity, but I thought it worth mentioning what should have been a prime opportunity.

Comment: I have had Demon Forges kill 3 Tormented Stingers at the same time more than once, but didnt get it. Maybe its because it was on normal difficulty. Which diff worked for you ?